# Height of java.awt.Graphics underlying device?

Tags: java, awt

I'm drawing a histogram (custom data, not related to coloring) on an BufferedImage. And I'd like to make it as wide and tall as possible. Can I do this passing only BufferedImage.createGraphics result to my drawing function? I can't find how to obtain image dimensions through an instance of Graphics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I do this passing only BufferedImage.createGraphics result to my drawing function?

I recommend to pass either:

1. The `BufferedImage` itself or
2. The `Graphics` instance and a [`Dimension`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dimension.html) (unless the plot *only* requires height, as opposed to WxH - then use an `int`).